# what is the correct way to define a non-alphanumeric char in c++?

Tags: c++

Sometimes I need to define a `char` which represents a non-alphanumeric `char`.

What is the correct way to define its value in C++?

Is using `EOF` or `char_traits<char>::eof()` a good choice?

Comment: Remember that `EOF` is not a `char`, it's an `int`.

Comment: I would say it depends what you need to represent. In general I'd avoid such _magic_ characters but it can't be a rule.

Comment: Hi joky and Adriano, In my case I want to initialize a char variable with a value which is non-alphanumric. But I dont want to use a magic value.

Comment: @camino Technically `(char) EOF` is often valid character. Exactly what character it is depends on the encoding (for example, in ISO-8859-1 it's `LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS`). It also depends on if `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: `EOF` is an `int`, typically with the value `-1`. It is *not* intended to be used as a `char` value; in fact it's specifically intended not to match any valid character. The fact that storing `EOF` in a `char` *might* give you `'ÿ'` is of no particular relevance (unless you see a `'ÿ'` in a program's output and can use it to track down a bug caused by misuse of `EOF`).

Comment: For other non-alphanumeric characters, you can place them between single quotes, such as '$'.  For the single quote, you would have to *escape* it: '\''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading too much in to the word `char`.

At the end of the day, it is little more than a size.  In this case, 8 bits.  Shorts are 16 (and you can wear them on the beach), ints can be 32 or something else, and longs can be 64 (or ints, or a quick conversation with the relevant authorities on the beach as to why you lost both pairs of shorts).

The correct way to define a value in C++ is basically down to what the maximum value that can be held.  `char_traits::eof()` is indeed a good constant, but out of context - means very little.

Comment: `char_traits::eof()` (actually `char_traits<char>::eof()`) is an `int` value, not a `char`, and it's specifically intended *not* to be a valid character value.

Answer (score 1):

`EOF` is not a `char` value; it's an `int` value that's returned by some functions to indicate that no valid character data could be obtained. If you're looking for a value to store in a `char` object, `EOF` is definitely not a good choice.

If your only requirement is to store *some* non-alphanumeric value in a `char` object (and you don't char which), just choose something. Any punctuation character will do.

```
char example = '*';
char another_example = '?';
char yet_another_example = '\b'; // backspace
```

This assumes I'm understanding your question correctly. As stated:

> Sometimes I need to define a `char` which represents a non-alphanumeric `char`.

it's not at all clear what you mean.  What exactly do you mean by "represents"? If you're looking for some arbitrary non-alphanumeric character, see above. If you're looking for some arbitrary value that merely *indicates* that you should have a non-alphanumeric character in some particular place, you can pick anything you like, as long as you use it consistently.

For example, `"DD-DD"` might be template representing two decimal digits, followed by a hyphen, followed by two more decimal digits -- but only if you establish and follow a convention that says that's what it means.

Please update your question to make it clear what you're asking.